# PInvoke signiture BSTR FAR*

Tags: c#, pinvoke

What should be the C# signiture for this function? (for pInvoke)

```
DWORD GetVatAccount(COleDateTime dtDateTime, BSTR FAR* strResult)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[DllImport("test.dll")]
private static extern int GetVatAccount(
    double dtDateTime, 
    StringBuilder strResult
);
```

or:

```
[DllImport("test.dll")]
private static extern int GetVatAccount(
    double dtDateTime, 
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.BStr)]ref string strResult
);
```

The conversions between the dates and double could be done with [DateTime.FromOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(VS.90).aspx) and [DateTime.ToOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate.aspx) methods.

Comment: does the return type to be int or uint? to work in all windows OS.
and what about the BSTR FAR * thing?

Comment: I am curious as to how passing a `double` for `COleDateTime` works. `COleDateTime` has two members, `DATE m_dt` and `DateTimeStatus m_status`. `DATE` is `typedef double DATE`, and if it only contained this variable I'd see how this *might* work. But a value for `m_status` needs to come from somewhere, no?